# Is it possible to turn Docker image into Windows executable for easy distribution?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, docker, virtualization

I have some desktop linux software, which I'd like to use on Windows and make it as much easy to install as possible. Easier than "*go install VirtualBox and use this Ubuntu image with all the preinstalled stuff*".

I've looked at "portable ubuntu project" (which can be run as usual win-32 application) but it does not feel like something robust, and has old 10 version of ubuntu in it. And seems like you can't use it on 64-bit Windows.

Or if there is no other way - can you recommend a way to create a super robust automatic windows installer which will install VirtualBox and create a virtual machine using snapshot? I need it to run smoothly on very wide range of new and old versions of MS Windows.

Or actually any thoughts on this topic would be much appreciated.

Comment: Even Docker Toolbox which is intended for old Windows versions requires: `To run Docker, your machine must have a 64-bit operating system running Windows 7 or higher` :(

Comment: FWIW, if you plan to install VirtualBox and create a Linux VM, the installer will not be fast, and will be HUGE. Your users may also not be thrilled about you installing and starting a VM to run the software.

Comment: @R0MANARMY that's true